# How to locate the webelement in the picture

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I need to locate the web element in the picture

[image]

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

To locate the desired element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span#filter-msg-ports[title='Multiple Ports']"));
  ```
- Using *Python* and *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Multiple Ports' and text()='Multiple Ports']")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if an element has an id attribute, using **By.id** locator is the best way to locate such element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("filter-msg-ports"));
```